# data clean before merge to rows pandas/python

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, data-cleaning

for a data set read from csv,for example,

```
id     street       suburb        postcode   timeStamp
A1      aa            BB            001       2016
A1      aa            BB            001       2019
```

I should merge rows with same id and if value conflict, use the latest one.So the data set after merge should be:

```
 id     street       suburb        postcode   timeStamp
A1      aa            BB            001       2019
```

but the data set in CSV is :

```
id     street            suburb        postcode   timeStamp
A1      aa                 BB            001      2016
A1      aa BB 001          None           None    2019
```

people might input the entire address inside the street column.
I think I need to clean the data before merge those 2rows.

Here is my current version, I didn't consider the above situation before merge.

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_csv("dd.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
df = df.sort_values(["id","timeStamp"])
duplicateRowsDF = df[df.duplicated(keep=False,subset='id')]
df=df.ffill().drop_duplicates('id',keep='last')
```

How should I clean the data like that ?
I am thinking if the value in this column is end with numbers, move the digits to postcode, and the word before postcode to suburb column...

New to programming and stackoverflow, let me know if is not clear.
Thanks

edit:
what if the suburb may more than one word, how could I split the suburb from street? split street after the word like 'St','Rd'etc?

```
    id     street                      suburb        postcode   timeStamp
A1      aa St                      pitt town       001      2016
A1      aa St pitt town  001       None           None      2019
```

Comment: I think your current code doesn't handle a couple of edge cases, e.g. incomplete data (suburb is `None`) for an id that appears just once. In this case the `ffill()` will fill the next row even if it's a different id. Also is the example you posted always the case for data being dirty, or are there other possibilities? Is it always the case that `street` column will contain suburb and postcode info? If so, I would start by using `split()` function to tokenize contents of `street` and copying to other columns.

Comment: yes, the current code will break for edge cases, that is why I want to fill all empty before    ffill() .(that is the only way I can come up with...) Yes, that is the only case these columns of data being dirty.  But I think split the line could be difficult, see update question. Thanks ~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in street are always separated by a " " then you can use the split method and grab the value you need for each column.  Then you can use the method drop duplicates and pass in a subset of the columns that you want to use as a determination for being a duplicate.

```
# Use only if 'None' is an actual string in your data
df = df.replace('None', np.nan)


df['suburb'] = df['suburb'].where(~df.suburb.isnull(), df.street.str.split().str[1])
df['postcode'] = df['postcode'].where(~df.postcode.isnull(), df.street.str.split().str[2])
df['street'] = df['street'].str.split().str[0]

df.head()

| id | street | suburb | postcode | timeStamp |
|----|--------|--------|----------|-----------|
| A1 | aa     | BB     | 001      | 2016      |
| A1 | aa     | BB     | 001      | 2019      |

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'street', 'suburb', 'postcode'], keep='last')

| id | street | suburb | postcode | timeStamp |
|----|--------|--------|----------|-----------|
| A1 | aa     | BB     | 001      | 2019      |
```

Comment: Thanks !  yes the reason for all data with empty suburb and postcode, because they put suburb and postcode in street.  However the real case is more complicated, the suburb may more than one word. .... I am thinking to split words after 'road', 'street', 'drive' etc. which could identify the end of the street. Do you think is possible to do that ?